# Is there a way to mention role in pm? discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Is there a way to mention role in a pm?

```
const patrion = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#f96854')
    .setTitle('Title')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setDescription('hey, ' + "<@" + message.author.id + ">" + '!')
    .addField('wow', 'wdwdwdwdwd', true)
    .addField('wow', 'wdwdwdwdwd', true)
    .addField('wow', "<@&" + 738333754631651388 + ">", true)
    .addField("Field", "Field" true)
    .setFooter("Footer")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're passing in the role snowflake as a number, due to the way javascript numbers work you may be referencing an invalid role. In addition to that discord's GUI may choose not to show a clickable role to the user or may even show "@deleted-role"

Comment: If i mention with this method in the guild, everything is fine.
I just don't know how to connect guild to the code, maybe that would work?

Comment: you can't. Besides the number that should be a string your code is correct, and technically speaking the role IS being mentioned, but the user won't be able to tell because of how discord's GUI works

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Role mentions only work in the same guild as the role exists.